# Sci-fi: maybe with a title like “a shock to the system”

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Colonists are faced with deciding whether to execute one of their members for a crime.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE. Unfortunately this isn't much to go on.. Could you please take a look at [this checklistlist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember? Was this a movie or a book? When did you read it? What was the crime? Why is it such a tough decision?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.   This question, if it is a question, is very short.  Are you asking for help identifying this short story?  If so, can you please provide every additional detail you can think of, such as when and where you read it, what the crime was, etc.

Comment: Hi and welcome, while we have you please take a look at the [tour], [help], [ask], [answer] to see how to work with the Stack Exchange format. It looks like you will need to [edit] more details in so we can help. Are you looking for [tag:story-identification]?

Comment: Possibly one of these: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=shock&C=AND&USE_2=title_title&O_2=contains&TERM_2=system&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title but not A Shock to Your System by Mandy Rosko which is a monster horror book.

Comment: As a precaution I've popped a notice on this to sort of indicate it was reopened under unusual circumstances and ward off speculative answers

Answer (score 10):

This is [Shock Treatment](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57573) by J. Francis McComas. I read it in the anthology [9 Tales of Space and Time](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?194).

> Based upon the humane philosophy reflected in the article referred to above, McComas has conceived a brave, struggling—and frightened—new world, a world rising slowly from the shattered remnants of a giant space ship which has crashed on a small, Earth-type planet in an unknown system. The problem of the story, and of Brandt Cardozo, the penologist of the survivors, is what to do with the ruthless murderer discovered in their midst.

Comment: A good find, especially given the poverty of information from OP.